# Select fields from table with DISTINCT field

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table of this type

```
| user | parents | sons |
```

with

- parents and sons columuns which can be NULL.
- user column can contains duplicated

I write this query:

```
SELECT user, COALESCE(parents, 0) AS parentsEd, COALESCE(sons, 0) AS sonsEd 
  FROM my_table 
  ORDER BY (parentsEd + sonsEd) DESC
```

and it works!
So it give a result with duplicated users.
How I can to have DISTINC users by using *(parentsEd + sonsEd) DESC* ORDER ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` before the order clause and if you want order results first then group them then use subselect

```
SELECT `user`, COALESCE(parents, 0) AS parentsEd, COALESCE(sons, 0) AS sonsEd
 FROM my_table GROUP BY `user` ORDER BY (parentsEd + sonsEd) DESC

SELECT DISTINCT `user`, COALESCE(parents, 0) AS parentsEd, COALESCE(sons, 0) AS sonsEd
 FROM my_table  ORDER BY (parentsEd + sonsEd) DESC


SELECT a.* FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT `user`, COALESCE(parents, 0) AS parentsEd, COALESCE(sons, 0) AS sonsEd
 FROM my_table  ORDER BY (parentsEd + sonsEd) DESC ) a GROUP BY a.`user`
```